# What is the probability of a specific arrangement of letters?

Tags: statistics

The letters of the word $STATISTICS$ are arranged in random order.  Find the probability that they spell $STATISTICS$.

There are are a total of 10 letters, hence, 10 positions to be filled.  There are 3 $S$'s, 3 $T$'s, 2 $I$'s, 1 $A$, and 1 $C$.

I know that the total number of distinct ways to arrange 3 $S$'s in 10 locations is ${10 \choose 3}$, and only 1 way will give the desired result.  Thus, the probability that the 3 $S$'s will be in the correct positions will be $\frac {1}{10 \choose 3}$.

Using this logic, the probability that a random arrangement of letters spells $STATISTICS$ is $$ \frac {1}{10 \choose 3} \cdot \frac {1}{10 \choose 3} \cdot \frac {1}{10 \choose 2} \cdot \frac {1}{10 \choose 1} \cdot \frac {1}{10 \choose 1} $$

Is this correct?

Edit:  The correct answer is $$ \frac {1}{10 \choose 3} \cdot \frac {1}{7 \choose 3} \cdot \frac {1}{4 \choose 2} \cdot \frac {1}{2 \choose 1} \cdot \frac {1}{1 \choose 1} $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct result is

$$\frac{1}{\frac{10!}{3!\cdot 3!\cdot 2!\cdot 1!\cdot 1!}}=\frac{3!\cdot 3!\cdot 2!\cdot 1!\cdot 1!}{10!}=\frac{1}{50400}\approx 2\cdot 10^{-5}$$

Comment: Reason : We have $10!$ arrangements for the letters, but changing the order of the $3$ S's does not change the resulting word. Same for the other letters

Comment: Google multinomial coefficient for more details

Comment: I understand.  So you calculated all possible permutations, and then removed the redundancies.  I still don't understand why my method is incorrect.

Comment: You start with the places for the $3$ S's and then you continue with the $3$ $T$'s, but $3$ places are already occupied. If you consider this, you should get the same result at the end

Comment: That fixes the problem.  Thanks!.